# How to put a condition on xml file upon which a configuration will load or not

Tags: java, xml

i have an XML file which holds some configurations that supply database connection.I am getting the database connection attributes from a java class ,now what i want that i need a condition in the XML file, if the condition is true then the tag which contains the database tag will be accessible otherwise will not.I  want to put a custom condition in my XML.I am posting my XML file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Adapter name="Hua_GPRS_CS5_4.7" type="ASN.1" version="1.0" description="Huawie GPRS Output CDR Version 4.7"
         execclass="hua.gprs.HuaGPRSFileExecutor" parallel="1" mode="server" statusfile="HuaGPRSStatus.csv"
         merge_factor="1" active="true">

i want to put conditions here 
    <DBConfig id="1" name="jjj" drivername="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" hostname="localhost" portname="1521"
              dbname="rrr" servicename="orcl" user="param" password="param" sid="orcl">
        <TableConfig ID="1" TableName="">
        </TableConfig>
    </DBConfig>


    <DirConfig>
        <poll protocol="" host="" path="./data/huagprs/source" pwd="" user="" clogging="true" startdir="" enddir=""
              pattern="(.*)\.(\d{6})(\d{6})(\d{4})_(.*)" metafields="fileName,exchange,fileDate,fileTime,fileSeq,junk"/>
        <source path="./data/huagprs/source" clogging="false"/>
        <backup path="./data/huagprs/backup" active="false"/>
        <staging path="./data/huagprs/staging" clogging="false"/>
        <output path="./data/huagprs/output" clogging="false" compress="gz"/>
        <error path="./data/huagprs/error" clogging="true"/>
        <target protocol="" host="" path="/" pwd="" user="" active="true"/>
    </DirConfig>

    <DataDefinition parser="com.etl.parser.core.CommaSepParser" type="#Grammar type#"
                    description="#Grammar Description#" ignoreinitLines="" fileheaderlines="1" datastartline="2"
                    recordseparator="\n" fieldseparator="," ignoreemptyrecord="FALSE">
        <Record parser="com.etl.parser.core.CommaSepParser" name="Statistics CDR" displayPos="null" givenName="null"
                separatorChar=","
                quoteChar="\\'" escapeChar="\n" ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace="FALSE" strictQuotes="FALSE"
                ignoreQuotes="FALSE" bracesHandle="FALSE">
        </Record>
    </DataDefinition>

</Adapter>
```

DBConfig  is my xml tag which contains the credentials i need the condition on this tag.i.e lets say  will be my custom tag where i will put my condition.

Comment: Are you expecting XML to evaluate some sort of condition? If so, that's like asking a cookbook to make you dinner.

Comment: no i am new in writing conditions in XML i heard about <xls:if> thats why i asked

Comment: @PaulDraper you r saying that it is impossible to write condition in XML

Comment: `xls:if` is a part of XSLT, which is an XML language for creating XML documents. That is, you can take an XSLT document, run it through an XSLT interpreter and get an XML document.

Comment: @PaulDraper is it possible to write condition in XML document or not?/

Comment: *I'm sorry if this is unclear, but it depends what you mean.* In one sense, you seem to be asking basically the equivalent of "Can I write a condition in a text file?" or "Can a cookbox make me dinner?" Not really, but it can tell you *how*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49296/discussion-between-lucifer-and-paul-draper)